# ActiveMQ 5.6 and password protecting JMX

Tags: activemq-classic, jmx

I went through the section "Password protecting the JMX connector" on: http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html

I have ***ActiveMQ 5.6*** installed.

In the activemq.xml file, I updated the following:

```
<managementContext>
     <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
  </managementContext>
```

And in bin/activemq, I updated the following:

**Before:**

```
# ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11099 "
# ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.password"
# ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.access"
# ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
```

**After:**

```
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=11099 "
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.password"
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=${ACTIVEMQ_CONF}/jmx.access"
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="$ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
```

I uncommented the lines for ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START.

After I uncommented them, I tried starting ActiveMQ, the server never came up.
Nothing showed up in the activemq.log file.

When I comment them back and start the server, it starts with no issue.

In order to isolate the issue, I uncommented the first line and tried starting, it never started.

Looks like it is expecting something else when I uncomment ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START.

I made sure that jmx.password and jmx.access exist under the conf folder.

Can you please let me know if I am missing something?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the ActiveMQ server started is that the file permission for jmx.password got to be:

```
chmod u=rw,go= jmx.password
```

I found this on: http://fusesource.com/docs/broker/5.5/security/JMX-AmqConnector-Authent.html

After updating permission, it worked fine.